# json[more levels] to dict python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

i'm having trouble with a simple question.

```
      a = {
          "apiVersion": "2.1",
          "data": {
               "startIndex": 1,
               "items": [{
                    "id": "YVA3UoZM0zU",
                    "title": "Trailer - Lisbela eo Prisioneiro"          
                        }]
                   }
       }
```

i don't know how to get the info id.
this is a string.
so, i tried to make this

```
           import simplejson as json
           >>> type(js)
           <type 'dict'>
           js = json.loads(a)
           print js['data'{'items'[{'id'}]}]
           >>> syntax error
```

this syntax is invalid, how could I get this info? it's supposed to be easy. where I'm making wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try:

```
js['data']['items'][0]['id']
```

It would appear that there may be multiple `items` in this structure. If you'd like to extract *all* item ids as a list, the following will do it:

```
[item['id'] for item in js['data']['items']]
```

Comment: thank you so much, that's the importance the community.
simple question, a lot of time expended in a just easy question.